# error message with 2sexy content module - dnn.controls is undefined

Tags: 2sxc

i get this error message at my dnn portal, where i use catalook and 2sexycontetn.
when i delete all 2sexymodules the message are gone.

i'm using dnn 9.0.2 and 2sexy 9.1.0 beta.

this is the error message with the firefox console

```
_loadScriptsInternal http://new12.aevo.at/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd:15:4695
_nextSession http://new12.aevo.at/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd:15:5238
_loadScriptsInternal http://new12.aevo.at/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd:15:4889
_scriptLoadedHandler http://new12.aevo.at/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd:15:5666
Function.createDelegate/< http://new12.aevo.at/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd:6:305
_scriptLoadHandler http://new12.aevo.at/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd:6:94283
Function.createDelegate/< http://new12.aevo.at/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd:6:305
b http://new12.aevo.at/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd:6:57480
```

where does 2sexycontent use the telrik controls?

thanks for help

michael

Answer (score 0):

Actually 2sxc doesn't use telerik controls, except in the edit-data dialog, IF a user tries to pick a file on DNN (instead of using ADAM). that's it.

The error you're experiencing is almost certainly a DNN 9 issue, related to managing js / css for the browser. I don't know anything about it, but I'm guessing that upgrading to dnn 9.1 should fix it.

Note: we'll release 2sxc 9.1 today, which should improve the user experience a lot :)